# Shifrin's 3500 Day 5 "$\mathbb{Q}^n$ is not a vector sub-space of $\mathbb{R}^n$." Is it a vector space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

In his lecture on vector subspaces, Dr. Shifrin gives the counterexample of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ not being a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I can't see a reason for it not to be a vector space, however.  Is it?  Similarly for $\mathbb{Z}^n.$

https://youtu.be/_FQqk6TFuhM?t=1177

Comment: "I can't see a reason for it not to be a vector space, " Not closed under arbitrary scalar multiplication by reals. For ex $\sqrt{2} \times 1 \notin \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely a vector space (under the field of $\mathbb Q$). However it is not a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb R^n$ because if you take a non-zero vector in it and multiply it by $\pi$ you escape the set, therefore it is not a subspace.

Remember that for something to be a vector space you need to say over which field and what the operations are. When you talk about subspaces of a fixed vector space then all you have to do is say which subset of the vectors you are taking and check the conditions are satisfied. Also note that $\mathbb Z^n$ is not a vector space over $\mathbb Z$ because $\mathbb Z$ isn't a field.

Comment: Are both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ vector spaces with field $\mathbb Q$ (with $\mathbb R$ having an infinite dimension)?

Comment: @Dmitry yes, you can view $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$, and moreover $\mathbb R$ is a field extension over $\mathbb Q$, but that isn't really what OP is asking.

Comment: @Jorge Can we define the circumference of a circle in $\mathbb{Q}^2$? I'm not saying the failure to be able to do so would prevent it from being a vector space.  It's just one of those things that make me wonder.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I haven't seen anyone talk about circles in $\mathbb Q^2$, but the usual distance still works in $\mathbb Q^2$ so you could define a circle as the points at a certain distance from a fixed point, but it's going to be missing most of the points that we recognize in our usual circles.